# Override default new user registration email with custom message (non sub-domain multi-site installation)

Tags: user-registration, pluggable

My problem is as follows. I have a multisite running on a non-sub-domain install. I am trying to customise the welcome email a user receives upon registration.

I managed to customise the welcome email by overriding `wp_new_user_notification` found in `pluggable.php` see [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126894/wpmu-signup-user-notification-filter-not-working), however this only overrides the message if you add a user through the top level network admin site, if you add through a lower level multisite the function does not apply.

Failing this I tried the following methods found on this site:

[How to Override A Function in ms-functions.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56797/how-to-override-a-function-in-ms-functions-php)

I am unsure quite how this works and if it could even be applied to what I am trying to achieve.

and:

[wpmu_signup_user_notification filter not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126894/wpmu-signup-user-notification-filter-not-working)

This produces a fatal already defined error.

Any advice on overriding files that aren't pluggable/anyone who has encountered this same problem would be great.

Comment: Did you override the function in a MU plugin or network-wide activated plugin? Or a regular plugin/theme?

Comment: I did not use MU plugin, current set up does not use that and would like (if possible) to avoid adding extra folders. I have the plugin network-wide activated.